# Turning on Vertex Attribute Divisor With Instanced Rendering Renders Nothing

Tags: opengl, rendering, vertex-attribute

When I render with glDrawArraysInstanced with the vertex attribute divisor set to zero, the triangle appears as expected. But when the divisor is set to any value other than zero, the triangle disappears. This is the code I am using to render:

```
static const u32 NUM_TRIANGLES = 1;
struct Vertex
{
    f32 x;
    f32 y;
 };
 static const Vertex g_triangles[NUM_TRIANGLES*3] = 
 {
    {0.125f, 0.125f},{-0.125f,0.125f},{-0.125f,-0.125f},
 };
 glGenVertexArrays(1, &g_vao);
 glBindVertexArray(g_vao);

 glGenBuffers(1, &g_vbo);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_vbo);
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_triangles), nullptr, 
             GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(g_triangles), 
                reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&g_triangles));
 glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 
                       reinterpret_cast<void*>(0));
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
 glVertexAttribDivisor(0, 1); // Setting this to 0 renders the triangle

 // This is the draw call
 glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, NUM_TRIANGLES);
```

Here are my shaders:

```
#version 420 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 v;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(v, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

#version 420 core
out vec4 out_color;
void main()
{
    out_color = vec4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
}
```

My problem is similar to
[OpenGL 2D instancing: glDrawArraysInstanced with a divisor renders nothing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/123931/opengl-2d-instancing-gldrawarraysinstanced-with-a-divisor-renders-nothing), but that question wasn't resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the attrib divisor means that each instance gets 1 copy of the attribute.

In your case it's easier to do

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*NUM_TRIANGLES);
```

Otherwise you need to make the offset a second attribute and then add them together in the vertex shader:

```
#version 420 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 v;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 instance_offset;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(v+instance_offset, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

and to bind it:

```
 static const Vertex g_triangles[3] = 
 {
    {0.125f, 0.125f},{-0.125f,0.125f},{-0.125f,-0.125f},
 };
 static const Vertex g_offsets[NUM_TRIANGLES] = 
 {
    {0f,0f},//...
 };
 glGenVertexArrays(1, &g_vao);
 glBindVertexArray(g_vao);

 glGenBuffers(1, &g_vbo);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_vbo);
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_triangles), nullptr, 
             GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(g_triangles), 
                reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&g_triangles));
 glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 
                       reinterpret_cast<void*>(0)); glGenBuffers(1, &g_vbo);

 glGenBuffers(1, &g_offset_vbo);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_offset_vbo);
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_offsets), nullptr, 
             GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(g_offsets), 
                reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&g_offsets));
 glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 
                       reinterpret_cast<void*>(0));
 glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1);
```

Comment: I'll accept it. But I still wonder why the divisor didn't work.

Comment: It did work, it just didn't do what you thought it did.